# how to hide top layout on recyclerview scrolling in viewpager

Tags: android

i am used bottom layout

i want hide tablayout, two layout of relative when recyclerview in viewpager

and if possiblely also want , normal layout visible after hide end

please some help

this my layout 
**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff">

<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/st_route_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/main_top_background"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    app:stl_clickable="true"
    app:stl_defaultTabBackground="@color/main_top_background"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextAllCaps="true"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="@color/main_top_background"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="10dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="65dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="@dimen/main_tab_title_size"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="false"
    app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_drawDecorationAfterTab="true"
    app:stl_indicatorAlwaysInCenter="false"
    app:stl_indicatorColor="#f2f2f2"
    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:stl_indicatorGravity="bottom"
    app:stl_indicatorInFront="true"
    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="linear"
    app:stl_indicatorThickness="1dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWidth="55dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWithoutPadding="false"
    app:stl_overlineThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp"


    />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/st_route_result"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:background="#11f2f2f2">

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_refresh"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rl_route_result_exit">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_route_result_refresh"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/main_search_station_refresh_un_real" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_route_result_live"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/livebtn"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_exit"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/exit_white" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/st_route_result"
    android:background="@color/main_top_background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_route_result_total_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/nomal_color_ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_route_result_total_station"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/nomal_color_ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_route_result_total_trans"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/nomal_color_ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_alarm"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rl_route_result_share">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_route_result_alarm"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/alarm_on" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_share"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rl_route_result_favorit">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/route_share" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_favorit"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_route_result_favorit"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/mymetro_unfavorit" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/rl_route_result_middle"
    android:background="@color/main_top_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_route_result_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_route_result_enter_train_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_enter_train_mark"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"

        android:src="@mipmap/mark_for" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_enter_train_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_enter_train_mark"
        android:text="탑승중"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_enter_train_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_enter_train_title"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="창동행 4335"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_enter_train_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tv_enter_train_dwon"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="11dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/list_down_white" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<adcapsule.smapp.View.Custom.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_route_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rl_route_result_bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Normal

[image]

After Scroll

[image]

If you are using recycler view inside viewpager follow steps below

```
1. take CoordinatorLayout as root layout
2. put all layouts in AppBarLayout you wanna hide on the scroll of recyclerview
   (also put TabLayout)
3. add viewpager after AppBarLayout
```

Add this line in view you want to hide(inside AppBarLayout )

```
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Add this line into viewpager

```
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

for example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new abstract class which extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener .

Then you can move item by set X,Y

```
public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

private int mToolbarOffset = 0;
private int mToolbarHeight;

public HidingScrollListener(Context context) {
    mToolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(context);
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    clipToolbarOffset();
    onMoved(mToolbarOffset);
    //The most important
    if((mToolbarOffset <mToolbarHeight && dy>0) || (mToolbarOffset >0 && dy<0)) {
        mToolbarOffset += dy;
    }
}

private void clipToolbarOffset() {
    if(mToolbarOffset > mToolbarHeight) {
        mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
    } else if(mToolbarOffset < 0) {
        mToolbarOffset = 0;
    }
}

public abstract void onMoved(int distance);}
```

how to use

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(createItemList());
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener(this) {
    @Override
    public void onMoved(int distance) {
        mToolbarContainer.setTranslationY(-distance);
    }
});}
```

There is a Chinese site .And it is much more complete

[click me ;)](http://www.jcodecraeer.com/a/anzhuokaifa/androidkaifa/2015/0319/2618.html)